# Why doesn't "./myprog | file" work like "cat file | ./myprog"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I am new to Python and would like to know different execution modes of the python program, say for below my program runs fine in first mode but second mode gives me error.

```
cat inputfile | ./pythonprogram.py   - works

./pythonprogram.py | inputfile  -- doesn't work
```

Also what are the all the best practices in executing the program through parsing input files.

FYI.. i am on the google python babyname exercise and below is my program:-

PS: I haven't coded a decent complete code, but this is more like a draft before attempting to execute full program.

Comment: what doesn't work about the second one?

Comment: These do completely different things. `./pythonprogram.py | inputfile` expects you to have a program named `inputfile` that can read the output from `pythonprogram.py`. If your `inputfile` isn't a program at all, then obviously this can't be expected to work.

Comment: This is a standard feature of the shell and nothing to do with python. `|` (pipe) sends the output of the lhs to the input of the rhs.

Comment: `./pythonprogram.py <inputfile` is the standard way to run your program with its stdin directed from `inputfile` without the overhead of an external tool such as `cat`, if that's what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: (As an aside, tacking on something like "Also what are all the best practices[...]" is a good way to make your question eligible for close-as-overbroad, even if it *had* been rule-compliant already. Try to keep your questions tightly scoped -- if you have something else to ask, that should generally be its own, separate question... if it complies with the Help Center guidelines, of course).

Comment: (...but that kind of "all the best practices" question just doesn't fly -- see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps mean:

```
./pythonprogram.py < inputfile
```

This takes the contents of `inputfile` and pipes it to your program.

On the other hand:

```
./pythonprogram.py | inputfile
```

Will take the output from your python program, try to execute inputfile (it can't), and then give it the output from the python program.

Comment: Triple-backticks don't work here. Use four-space indents for multi-line code blocks.

Comment: Backticks appeared to work on one line. I changed it anyway.

Comment: The formatting's different -- the grey background only extends where the text is with the backticks within a single line, whereas here you'll see they extend all the way to the border on the right.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Meant to do it this anyway, but sometimes get confused with different systems each with their own slightly different set of rules.

Comment: Yup. I'm a fan of GitHub-flavored markdown myself, so I do feel your pain on this one.